# OWIN StaticFiles not found gives status 500

Tags: asp.net, iis, owin

When using OWIN in the IIS integrated pipeline, I want to add `UseStaticFiles` to my component. In the Startup class of my app, I have configured this like so:

```
var filesystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("./Scripts");
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { RequestPath = new PathString("/files"), FileSystem = filesystem });
```

To get this working, I need to convince IIS to handle the request to `/files/myfile.js` to ASP.NET, so my OWIN component can handle it.

The RAMMFAR method somehow doesn't work for me, but I found out that

```
<add name="MyStaticFiles-Handler" path="/files/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

will do the trick. However, when I request `/files/does-not-exist.js`, I get a status 500 instead of 404.

I have no idea if my TransferRequestHandler is the right method, and whether this 500 is expected. How can I make sure that non-existent files in `/files/*` get served as 404 instead of 500?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make static files work with IIS, enabling RAMMFAR is not enough: you also need to call `app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler)` after calling `app.UseStaticFiles(...)`, as indicated on the documentation: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Static%20Files%20on%20IIS&referringTitle=Documentation

```
var filesystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("./Scripts");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { RequestPath = new PathString("/files"), FileSystem = filesystem });

app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
```

Comment: I had `app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);` before UseStaticFiles... Now I understand UseStageMarker better!